# Jetty + Jersey + Spring DI with no web.xml

Tags: spring, servlets, jersey, jetty, jax-rs

I am trying to write a small REST application using an embedded Jetty 9 server and a Jersey (2.18) servlet. I would like to use Spring 4 for Dependency Injection, but I am having troubles to inject spring beans in Jersey resources.
I am configuring the server programmatically, so no web.xml.

My Jersey resource config is:

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

  public static final String ROOT_PACKAGE = "com.example";

  public ApplicationConfig() {
    packages(true, ROOT_PACKAGE);

    // Features
    register(JacksonFeature.class);

    property(METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE, true);

  }
}
```

The main class (where I'm configuring and starting Jetty) is:

```
public class Runner {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationConfig applicationConfig = new ApplicationConfig();

    ServletHolder jerseyServlet = new ServletHolder(new ServletContainer(applicationConfig));

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();

    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.addServlet(jerseyServlet, "/rest/*");

    context.addEventListener(new ContextLoaderListener());
    context.addEventListener(new RequestContextListener());

    context.setInitParameter("contextClass", AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class.getName());
    context.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", ProductionSpringConfig.class.getName());

    Server server = new Server(8080);
    server.setHandler(context);

    try {
      server.start();
      server.join();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

The spring configurations is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
public class ProductionSpringConfig {}
```

I have added a simple Spring component in the scanned package and I can see it is correctly instantiated when the Server starts:

```
@Component
public class BeanExample {

  public void doSomething(){
    System.out.println("HelloWorld");
  }
}
```

When I try to inject it into a Jersey resource though, it is always null. I tried using both the Autowired and Inject annotations.
I'm pretty sure I misunderstood something and I didn't configure all the pieces properly.

Could anybody help please?

Comment: I don't see any spot in here where you register `SpringComponentProvider`, since you're doing this in an SE way you'll likely need to register that yourself.

Comment: Your example works fine for me. Do you have a small Github project you can share, that demonstrates the problem? Here's [what I used that works](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-jetty). I thought it might be the `METAINF_SERVICES_LOOKUP_DISABLE` which causes the `SpringComponentProvider` to not be found, but it seems to still work even with that property.

Comment: @peeskillet I had a look at the code you published on github and I noticed that you imported jersey-spring3 as part of your dependencies. I did the same and now it's working fine.
Thanks for your help